# Hashing PHP Session when user share the same IP Address and Identical User Agent

Tags: php, security, session, fingerprint

Refer to my question I posted on [Stack Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/96623/session-identification-hashing-how-to-make-it-more-secure-and-robust), I am using

```
md5($this->_user_agent.self::SECURE_SESSION . $this->_ip_address);
```

for generating a session fingerprint( and also as a added security measure regenerating Session Id after every 10 minutes). It looks fine, but I want to deal with a situation when a attacker exploit an victim in the same network[ip address], uses the same User agent , and has also stolen the Session ID, now my above check will fail in that case.

Few solution I found while Googling around are  using `Flash Cookies or EverCookies or a jquery browser fingerprinting plugin`. But all of this got their own pros and cons. Also I want to avoid Flash Cookies etc ( as it violates EU laws & intrude User's privacy also at same time).

So as a workaround I have modified my fingerprinting a bit and added `php_uname()`, `PHP_OS` in it .

Now my above fingerprinting method became,

```
md5($this->_user_agent. self::SECURE_SESSION . $this->_ip_address.php_uname().PHP_OS);
```

I know it is not also a Robust or Complete solution, but does adding the two more constraints made my fingerprinting a bit more Secure or has got no impact at all ?

> PS: I am posting it here instead of security , as I think reach of
>   statckoverflow is more .

Comment: `has also stolen the Session ID` https solves that, doesn't it ? also remote_ip fingerprinting can AFAIK kick some users which are behind a sort of balancing proxy (which has multiple changing www-IPs)

Comment: HTTPS will solve that I know.But I was talking in a more general terms in HTTP scenario. FYR https://github.com/n01ze/SecuredSessionmanagerClass